# Pure Android device with 2GB+ RAM in the size of an iPhone SE?

Tags: android

My current device is [Moto X (2013)](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_x-5601.php), the dimensions are perfect. I am surprised to see that Android [does not offer many options in that dimension](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?nYearMin=2016&nHeightMin=120&nHeightMax=130&nRamMin=2000&sAvailabilities=1,2,5&sOSes=2), I was unable to find any of the phones in the local market. Do you know of any device? I want a device close to pure Android. Since the Moto X was launched by Google the OS was nice.

I was sure that the Pixel line will have a device of the dimension as Apple's iPhone SE. I am looking for a device from Google, HTC or LG.

Comment: Actually the Moto X is a Motorola phone. Yes Motorola had been acquired by Google at the time but Google didn't change anything when in comes to the phones that were on the market. Google mainly bought Motorola for the in house development for their projects and because of all the patents Motorola had that Google wanten to protect Android.

Comment: Part of the issue(I believe) I have determined is that Android devices are battery hogs especially on recent versions so part of space is taken up by increased battery sizes.

Comment: I think the [Sony Xperia X Compact](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_x_compact-8292.php) is a 4.6" .